# Ensure action being called using ssl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With c# mvc, how do I ensure that a specific Action is being invoked over ssl?

For example on a payments page, my server allows https/http but I want to enforce the user accessing it uses https?

I am thinking something like an actionfilter that redirects them to https if they arent using it?

Is it a correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And two seconds later, part of framework of course.

[RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In your case  `[RequireHttp]` attribute might do the trick if you clear out the login cookie - or you'll be sending it in clear text across the wire. It might be more work than it's worth to avoid the slight cost of further `HTTPS calls.` SO is all about recycling questions and other users reading your question might think it's OK to drop down to HTTP after login, when it's usually the wrong thing to do.

The `[RequireHttps]` attribute can be **used on a controller type** or action method to say **"this can be accessed only via SSL."**  Non-SSL requests to the controller or action will be redirected to the SSL version (if an HTTP GET) or rejected (if an HTTP POST).  You can override the RequireHttpsAttribute and change this behavior if you wish.  There's no [RequireHttp] attribute built-in that does the opposite, but you could easily make your own if you desired.

There are also overloads of Html.ActionLink() which take a protocol parameter; you can explicitly specify "http" or "https" as the protocol.  Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx) on one such overload.  If you don't specify a protocol or if you call an overload which doesn't have a protocol parameter, it's assumed you wanted the link to have the same protocol as the current request.

The reason we don’t have a [RequireHttp] attribute in MVC is that there’s not really much benefit to it.  It’s not as interesting as [RequireHttps], and it encourages users to do the wrong thing.  For example, many web sites log in via SSL and redirect back to HTTP after you’re logged in, ***which is absolutely the wrong thing to do***.  Your login cookie is just as secret as your username + password, and now you’re sending it in cleartext across the wire.  Besides, you’ve already taken the time to perform the handshake and secure the channel (which is the bulk of what makes HTTPS slower than HTTP) before the MVC pipeline is run, so [RequireHttp] won’t make the current request or future requests much faster.